# Simplifying a dot and cross product expression

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, vector-fields, cross-product

I am trying to solve or simplify
$$ \left[ \,f\cdot \frac{(u\times v)}{||u\times v||_2} \right]\frac{(u\times v)}{||u\times v||_2} = 0 $$
where $f$ is a unit vector and $u,v$ are vectors.

*Is there a way to simplify this?*

I have been trying to use some of [the triple product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) e.g. ${\displaystyle (\mathbf {a} \cdot (\mathbf {b} \times \mathbf {c} ))\,\mathbf {a} =(\mathbf {a} \times \mathbf {b} )\times (\mathbf {a} \times \mathbf {c} )}$, but have only really made things more complicated.

Comment: Curious as to where this comes from?

Comment: Try to break it down into its simplest parts and ask what do you need to know in order for that vector to be zero.

Comment: This equation says that either $u$ and $v$ are parallel or that the component of $f$ perpendicular to them both is zero, I.e., that $f$ lies in the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @ElSpiffy It comes from me playing around with some flow equations ($f,u,v$ are all dependent on space-time position) :)

Comment: @amd Hmm, $u,v$ can be assumed to never be parallel. In this case, are you saying that the equation is true iff $f\in\text{span}\{u,v\}$? Thanks for that geometric intuition btw, I was getting lost in stupid algebra.

Comment: @user3658307 The l.h.s. is the projection of $f$ onto $u\times v$. If you take $f$ as variable, it’s the point-normal equation for the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$.

Comment: What is the unknown ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u,v$ cannot be parallel, otherwise the LHS would be undefined. Then your equation simplifies to

$$f\cdot(u\times v)=0$$ which expresses that the vectors $f,u,v$ are linearly dependent.

$$\lambda f+\mu u+\nu v=0,$$ with $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ not all zero.

Answer (score 1):

Because $0$ on the right side means zero vector and $u \times v $ is non-zero vector then it must be 
$$   \,f\cdot  (u\times v)     = 0 $$
($0$ here is a scalar) .

Further I think it can't be simplified but it can be written alternatively  in the matrix form $f^TS(u)v=0$ where skew-symmetric matrix $S(u)=[ u \times i \ \ \ \   u \times j \ \ \ \  u \times k ]$ is generated from the vector products of $u$ with standard basis vectors $i,j,k$.